# Can't send managed file as mail attachment

Tags: 7, emails

I'm working on a form submit in a Drupal 7 project, the form has and upload file field, in my form submit handler I can get the file id, what I want to do is to send and mail which has as attachment the uploaded file.

my form submit function:

```
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $fid = $form_state['values']['document'];
  $file = file_load($fid);
  $params = array(
    'attachment' => $file,
  );
  global $language;
    drupal_mail('my_module', 'key_1', 'my_own_mail@gmail.com', $language, $params);

}
```

hook_mail implementation:

```
function my_module_mail($key, &$message, $params){
  switch ($key) {
    case 'key_1':
      $message['subject'] = t('my mail subject');
      $message['body'][] = t('Hello this is a test content');
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment'];
  }
}
```

When submitting the form the mail has not been sent and this error is shown:

```
Error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in my_module_mail()
```

Anybody has an idea why it doesn't accept object and or how to deal with this in this case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[file_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_load/7.x) return file object:

> Loads a single file object from the database.

But `$message['params']['attachments'][]` should be an array.
So just change `$file = file_load($fid);` to `$file = (array)file_load($fid);` in your submit function `my_form_submit` will be like:

```
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $fid = $form_state['values']['document'];
  //file object as an array. 
  $file = (array)file_load($fid);
  $params = array(
    'attachment' => $file,
  );
  global $language;
    drupal_mail('my_module', 'key_1', 'my_own_mail@gmail.com', $language, $params);

}
```

**Update**:

to send attachement you need just the `filePath` try with:

```
$params = array(
    'attachments' => array(
      0 => array(
        'filepath' => $file->uri,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: yes I've already test it the error message disappeared but on mail delivery there is no attachments.

Comment: yeah i had that issue, check the update. and tell me if its works.

Comment: i'm glad that help, you are so welcome man.